# Adding a javascript file to the "blank" template in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento 1.5 (CE) and I'm slowly getting my head around it (how confusing is this piece of software?).

I want to add a js file to all my pages, but I'm not sure what i need to edit. I have created a file called `app.js` located in `/skin/frontend/default/blank/js` how do i add this file to all my templates?

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654822/how-to-add-adding-external-javascript-in-magento?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: What xml layout file is being referenced in the first block?

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `local.xml` in your theme's layout directory, and add the following block:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">     
            <script>app.js</script>                         
        </action> 
    </reference>
</default>
```

Another common, related request is to allow this JS to be turned off conditionally. Magento supports this as well:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs" ifconfig="yourmodule/someconfig/boolfield">      
            <script>app.js</script>                         
        </action> 
    </reference>
</default>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: That's how it's done, only issue I have is that most javascript should be added in the footer, not the head, to improve page rendering speed.