# Adding external JS/CSS to Magento website

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento

I'm trying to add external css and javascripts to my magento website. What I basically did was to put the necessary scripts in their respective directories, then add this code to the page.xml of both the default and my current theme in app/design/frontend:

```
            <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/modernizr.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/jquery.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/foundation.min.js</script></action>


            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/foundation.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/flexslider.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/main.css</stylesheet></action>
```

But it seems that it's not showing on the head tag on every page I have. What else have I missed that makes the loading not possible?

I'm using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0.

Comment: "Adding external JavaScript file to Magento" -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654822/adding-external-javascript-file-to-magento

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below just put your js in `yourapplication/js/foundation`

And you can add xml code to your local or your any design xml file like

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/modernizr.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/jquery.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/foundation.min.js</script></action>
 </reference>
```

but you should have to maintain loading sequence in proper way.

hope this will sure help you.