# Magento javascript double called and wrong path

Tags: javascript, magento

Magento calls my merged javascript file but also calls other "loose" javascript files.
This only happens on the category and productpages.

The extra javascript files have the wrong path, so there are 404 errors.
for example: url.com/category/sub-category/js/bieb/jquery.sortportfolio.min.js

See also the magento website: http://ongedierteproducten.nl/boktor/boktor-bestrijdingsmiddelen/embasol-boktor-dood-5-liter-20-m2

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey everything looks fine..where is the problem?

Comment: inspect with firebug or chrome. You will see that many js files get a 404 error on the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should not using Relative Paths in magento

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ongedierteproducten.nl/js/slider/jquery.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bieb/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bieb/jquery.quicksand.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bieb/jquery.sortportfolio.min.js"></script>
```

Instead you should add your javascript using

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>folder/file.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

See [Adding external JavaScript file to Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654822/adding-external-javascript-file-to-magento)

Comment: I checked page.xml the files are coded there as you said. Only I cant find the above files in page.xml or catelog.xml . You maybe know where I can find the js files of my post?

Comment: Since it doesn't have a domain name in the url, more than likely it is included in a .phtml file. Check your header.phtml, do a global search for or turn on magento developer tool to see the name of the block/phtml